# UISplitViewController with a UIImageView on the Top?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uisplitviewcontroller

What I want is the normal UISplitViewController, except it's moved down about 100px down so that an image can be at the top.

I tried to put the following in the splitviewcontroller init:

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 140, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

but that didn't do anything.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UISplitViewController is built to take all the screen real estate and not really let you do any sort of custom design, even something as trivial as modifying it's frame. 
I suggest you take a look at [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad) if you want to a customizable UISplitViewController.

*Also don't forget to modify the frame's height, so part of what your drawing isn't off screen (ex. CGRectMake(0, 140, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height**-140**)];)*.

Answer (score 1):

Remy's advice is excellent here.  Apple really went out of their way to prevent us from customizing UISplitViewController.  MGSplitViewController is a good alternative.  The only thing I'd add is that the init method is generally not the best place to adjust your view's frame, as UIKit tends to resize your view controller's view prior to display.  A better place to adjust the frame is in `viewWillAppear:`.